# JavaScript "new Date" creating date with time different from original date string

Tags: javascript, datetime

I am getting a date as a string `'2018-10-15 00:00:00.000'`, then converting it to a date using `new Date('2018-10-15 00:00:00.000')`.

I am persisting this date to a database (with API) and it is saving the data as `2018-10-15 **04**:00:00.000`. Note the 4 am time. The API gets the date time as 4:00 am.

[image]

In my angular application, the object that holds this date is defined as `Date` type.

```
meeting_date: Date;
```

This is from the console.

```
dt = new Date('2018-10-15 00:00:00.000')
Mon Oct 15 2018 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)

JSON.stringify(dt)
""2018-10-15T04:00:00.000Z""
```

I want to save the date as `2018-10-15 00:00:00.000`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: it depends on your db / server timezone and locale, save timestamp instead

Comment: Welcome to the nightmare that is Dates and Times in code. The issue is almost certainly a difference between the timezones in the browser, on the web server and in the database. If you use a UTC timestamp then this problem should resolve itself.

Comment: thanks. Let me try UTC timestamp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the date input string you are getting represents UTC, then you probably want to create the `Date` object in UTC (your current approach is creating the `Date` object in local time on the client machine, which is why the EDT offset is affecting the datetime you are storing in your db). Also, you should be aware that `Date()` is [not recommended for parsing date strings due to browser inconsistencies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#Parameters).

Following is an example using some simple regex to parse the string and create the `Date` object in UTC:

```js
const str = '2018-10-15 00:00:00.000';
const [y, m, d, hh, mm, ss, ms] = str.match(/\d+/g);
const date = new Date(Date.UTC(y, m - 1, d, hh, mm, ss, ms));
console.log(JSON.stringify(date));

// date as UTC string
console.log(date.toUTCString());

// date as local string
console.log(date.toString());
```

Comment: Upvoted for `let [y, m, d, hh, mm, ss, ms] = inputDate.match(/\d+/g);` I have never seen that before but man that makes working with date strings easy!

Comment: @AdamH - it is useful for these sorts of date strings. Date strings with alpha months, etc have to be handled a bit differently.